# How the buy/sell rate of bitcoin is continuosly increasing?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, currencies, cryptography

I am continuously monitoring bitcoin rate since last one month using an android app (zebpay). The buy/sell rate reached double fold within one month. I never seen it decreasing. 
Considering me a naive in understating crypto currency, I have following question:

1. Is it predictable currency and I should buy some bitcoin to sell it after few days to gain profit?
2. Which factor is responsible for such increasing rate (never seen any currency with such exponential curve)?

Comment: No, it's definitely not "predictable"; if you look at [historical prices](https://99bitcoins.com/price-chart-history/) you will see many declines, many of them rapid.  If you buy some bitcoin, it is entirely possible that the price will go down and you will lose money when you sell; you could lose a large fraction of your investment.  We cannot predict how the price will move in the future and such questions are off topic for this site.